# Delphi Error: 'Dataset not in edit or insert mode'

Tags: delphi, dataset

So, I Googled the following, but cannot seem to find an answer.
I've got a few Access tables that I am trying to update from Delphi.
The one table updates perfectly, so I know my database connection is active (the connection is set when the main form loads).
The problem is the second table. I keep on getting the error: "Dataset not in edit or insert mode".

In the formshow procedure I've got the following code:

```
     //Connect to the individuals details table
     dmoDonations.tblInd.Connection:= dmoDonations.adoDonations;
     dmoDonations.tblInd.ReadOnly:= False; //Enable read / write
     dmoDonations.tblInd.Active:= False;
     dmoDonations.tblInd.TableName:='Individuals';
     dmoDonations.tblInd.Active:= True;

     dmoDonations.tblInd.Append; //Insert new record

     dmoDonations.cdsInd.Open;
     dmoDonations.cdsInd.Active:= True;
     dmoDonations.cdsInd.ReadOnly:= False;
     dmoDonations.cdsInd.Refresh;
```

And the rest of the code to update the table is under the updateButtonClick procedure:

```
    dmoDonations.tblInd.Insert; //Insert new record

    dmoDonations.tblInd['Name']:= edtName.Text;
    dmoDonations.tblInd['Address1']:= edtAddress1.Text;
    dmoDonations.tblInd['Address2']:= edtAddress2.Text;
    dmoDonations.tblInd['Address3']:= edtAddress3.Text;
    dmoDonations.tblInd['Phone']:= edtPhone.Text;
    dmoDonations.tblInd['Email']:= edtEmail.Text;

    dmoDonations.tblInd.Post; //Saves new records
```

It's at the last line where the error pops up when I step through the code. Why would this error occur even though the table is open and active and I've inserted / appended the table (have tried both options in both sections of code)?

Comment: Why are you doing both an append then insert? Remove the `tblInd.Append` completely. Does that change things? (The call to `cdsInd.Open` and then `cdsInd.Active := True;` are also redundant; `Open` and `Active := True;` both do the same thing, so you're opening the client dataset twice in sequential lines of code. You also don't  need to call `Refresh` immediately after opening the CDS.

Comment: @KenWhite The append and insert are both there since I was trying everything I could think of. I tried your suggestions (thank you) but still get the same error.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you so much! played around a bit with some of the other pieces of code that also accesses the tables with your changes and now my tables are updating beautifully.